# Setting today as an ASP.Net SqlDataSource insert parameter default value

Tags: asp.net, parameters, default-value, sqldatasource

Using this ASP.Net we would like to see today's date appear in a date Textbox when the user clicks the "New" button of a DetailsView so they can see the date in the Textbox prior to actually inserting the data.

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ClassID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="StudentID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Absent" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Late" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="LateTimeArrivedAtSchool" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="DateAttendanceTaken"  DefaultValue= "<%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>"/>
</InsertParameters>
```

I already tried to use DefaultValue = "<%=DateTime.Now.ToString() %>" but no date appears in the Textbox.

This is the markup for the textbox which is in the DetailsView:

```
<asp:TemplateField 
    HeaderText="Attendance Date:" SortExpression="DateAttendanceTaken">

    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox 
            ID="TextBoxDateAttendanceTaken" 
            runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("DateAttendanceTaken", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorEditDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDateAttendanceTaken" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter the Attendance Date." Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" 
            SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>

    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox 
            ID="TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert" 
            runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("DateAttendanceTaken", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorInsertDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter the Attendance Date." Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Red" 
            SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </InsertItemTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label 
            ID="LabelDateAttendanceTaken" 
            runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("DateAttendanceTaken", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

*** UPDATE ***

I found out that to get this to work, OnDataBinding needs to be added as shown here plus making sure there is a handler in the code-behind file as shown below.

InsertItemTemplate markup:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox 
        ID="TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert" 
        runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Bind("DateAttendanceTaken", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'
        OnDataBinding="TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert_DataBinding">
    </asp:TextBox>

</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Handler in the code-behind file:

```
Protected Sub TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim txtBox As New TextBox
    txtBox = DetailsView.FindControl("TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert")
    txtBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("d")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the post back of the new button to set the textbox by grabbing the ListView's insert item and finding the `TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert` textbox.

Set the value of the textbox to `DateTime.Now`.

[The Insert Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.insertitem%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
protected void NewButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code to change to set Insert
    //get insert item
    object control = MyDetailsView.FindControl("TextBoxDateAttendanceTaken")
    //check for null
    if(control != null){
        TextBox tBox = (TextBox)control; //cast to TextBox
        tBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //set text
    }
}
```

VB:

```
Dim tBox As TextBox =  CType(MyDetailsView.FindControl("TextBoxDateAttendanceTaken"), TextBox)
tBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
```

That should do it, it just sets the textbox in the insert item to the current datetime each time new is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you show sample coding since I don't know how to do that coding? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. To make things easier for you this is in a web page based on a MasterPage with the content id called "ContentBody" if that helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the coding. I tried to convert it to VB.Net with a converter but the converter says there's an error on the object control = line.

Comment: Thanks and almost there. I get this error maybe because it's a DetailsView and not a ListView: Error 1 Argument not specified for parameter 'causesValidation' of 'Public Overridable Sub InsertItem(causesValidation As Boolean)'. C:\Development\Knowledge Academy Internal\Knowledge Academy\Knowledge Academy\Attendance.aspx.vb 148 51 Knowledge Academy

Comment: Thanks for the correction. The code compiles and when I click the new button there is this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Looks like FindControl is not finding it. I made sure the spelling is correct by copying the name directly from the markup id of the textbox.

Comment: Are you changing the mode first?

Comment: No. Just trapping the click event in:    Protected Sub ButtonNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim tBox As TextBox = CType(DetailsView.FindControl("TextBoxDateAttendanceTakenInsert"), TextBox)
        tBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
    End Sub
I will try to change the mode to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried adding: DetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert) but still got the error on the tBox.Text = line. If I comment out that line, I can see that the DetailsView goes into Insert mode without explicitly putting it into Insert mode. I also tried to create a label called LabelTodaysDate and was able to put today's date into that label from a simple  LabelTodaysDate.Text = Today command. Is there a way to get this value into the asp:parameter DefaultValue = ... ?

Comment: You can do a statement like your bind <%# DateTime.Now %> (the difference is the # not =)

Comment: Thanks for trying but it will not allow binding there so I think we will just use GetDate inside the asp:SqlDataSouce and live with not showing the date until the user re-displays the data.

Comment: Thanks for the coding. I found that the coding will work if OnDataBinding is used in the insert template that will call a handler in the code-behind file. I updated the post to show the actual coding we used.